# Which platforms can the most Final Fantasy games be found?

Tags: final-fantasy-series

I'm interested in (re)playing as many of the Final Fantasy games as I possibly can, but I'm limited in the number of various platforms I have access to (what I have access to isn't important - I don't mind picking up a new console or something, but I don't want to have to buy 5 different consoles). What platform(s) currently support the most number of Final Fantasy games?

The term "Final Fantasy game" specifically refers to the primary core of games which are titled as "Final Fantasy n". However, answers may include [sequels and derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy#Remakes.2C_sequels_and_spin-offs) such as Final Fantasy Tactics and Kingdom Hearts as either a separate section or as a dedicated answer. Also, emulators could also be considered if there is a readily-available legal source of ROMs for that platform.

Comment: Many FF games are being remastered or released on Steam for example but I think the Playstation would be your safest bet (if you could get your hand on a older Ps3 which had backward compatibility, you would be fit for 7 to 13, SNES for 4 to 6 at least). Seems the Playstation wins the FF [by a good margin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_video_games)

Comment: I was unaware of FF games showing up on Steam. I know there's quite a few of the older core games on the Android marketplace, which I suspect might have the most available games once emulators are factored in, but I'm not sure and haven't found any sources with definitive information.

Comment: Also, some FF games have also been release on the playstation store as downloadable games, I bought FF 7 that way.

Comment: If you are aiming for quantity on 1 console (and are willing to look for a PS1 Memory card, because you can't save ps1 games on ps2 memory card) I would suggest PS2 + PC with emulators for old consoles (because it's REALLY hard to get your hands on old cartridges that work). This combination has games 1-12 + a bunch of parallel games.

Comment: There's some great answers here, but Square Enix just announced that they are remaking (not porting) Final Fantasy VII for the PS4. So, that pretty much answers which console to get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The console with most FF games is playstation. (anthology, Chronicles, origin) have more than 1 FF game from NES/SNES.

**If counting digital downloads**, then the PS3 is the console with the most FF games.

Gameboy

```
Final Fantasy: Legend I
Final Fantasy: Legend II    
Final Fantasy: Legend III
Final Fantasy Adventure
```

Gameboy Advance

```
Final Fantasy IV Advance    
Final Fantasy V Advance 
Final Fantasy VI Advance        
Final Fantasy Tactics Advance       
Final Fantasy: Dawn of Souls
```

Gamecube

```
Final Fantasy Crystal Chronicles
```

iOS, Android

```
Final Fantasy I
Final Fantasy II
Final Fantasy IV
Final Fantasy V
Final Fantasy VI
Final Fantasy Tactics
Final Fantasy Dimensions
Final Fantasy All the Bravest
Final Fantasy Record Keeper
```

Mobile Phone

```
Before Crisis: Final Fantasy VII        
Crisis Core: Final Fantasy VII
Final Fantasy IV: The After Years
```

Nintendo (NES)

```
Final Fantasy I     
Final Fantasy II    
Final Fantasy III
```

Nintendo 3ds

```
Theatrhythm Final Fantasy   Nintendo 3DS
```

Nintendo DS

```
FF Crystal Chronicles: Ring of Fates    
FF Tactics A2: Grimoire of the Rift 
Final Fantasy III DS    
Final Fantasy IV DS
Final Fantasy XII: Revenant Wings   
Final Fantasy: The 4 Heroes of Light
FF Crystal Chronicles: Echoes of Time
```

Playstation

```
Final Fantasy VII       
Final Fantasy VIII      
Final Fantasy IX        
Final Fantasy Tactics       
Final Fantasy: Anthology        
Final Fantasy: Chronicles       
Final Fantasy: Origins
```

Playstation 2

```
Final Fantasy X     
Final Fantasy XII   
Final Fantasy X-2   
Dirge of Cerberus: Final Fantasy VII
Final Fantasy XI
```

PC

```
Final Fantasy III
Final Fantasy IV
Final Fantasy VII
Final Fantasy VIII
Final Fantasy XI
Final Fantasy XIII
Final Fantasy XIII-2
Final Fantasy XIV
```

Xbox 360

```
Final Fantasy XI
Final Fantasy XIII
Final Fantasy XIII-2
Lightning Returns: Final Fantasy XIII
```

Playstation 3

```
Final Fantasy XI    
Final Fantasy XIV (Realm Reborn)    
Final Fantasy XIII  
Final Fantasy XIII-2        
Lightning Returns: Final Fantasy XIII   
-----PSN-----
Final Fantasy I
Final Fantasy II
Final Fantasy Origins
Final Fantasy IV
Final Fantasy V
Final Fantasy VI
Final Fantasy VII
Final Fantasy VIII
Final Fnatasy IX
Final Fantasy X-X2
Final Fantasy XII-2
Final Fantasy Tactics
Crystal Defenders
```

Playstation 4

```
Final Fantasy XIV (Realm Reborn)
Final Fantasy XV
The Reason Final Fantasy Type-0
Final Fantasy X-X2 HD
-----PSN-----
Final Fantasy I
Final Fantasy II
Final Fantasy Origins
Final Fantasy IV
Final Fantasy V
Final Fantasy VI
Final Fantasy VII
Final Fantasy VIII
Final Fnatasy IX
Final Fantasy X-X2
Final Fantasy XII-2
Final Fantasy Tactics
Crystal Defenders
```

Playstation Portable (PSP)

```
Final Fantasy Tactics: War of the Lions 
Final Fantasy IV: The Complete Collection   
Dissidia Final Fantasy      
Final Fantasy Type-0        
Dissidia 012 Final Fantasy  
Final Fantasy Anniversary Edition   
Final Fantasy II Anniversary Edition
Final Fantasy IV: The After Years   
----PSN---
Final Fantasy I
Final Fantasy II
Final Fantasy Origins
Final Fantasy III
Final Fantasy IV
Final Fantasy V
Final Fantasy VI
Final Fantasy VII
Final Fantasy VIII
Final Fantasy IX
```

Super Nintendo (SNES)

```
Final Fantasy IV        
Final Fantasy V 
Final Fantasy VI        
Final Fantasy: Mystic Quest
```

Wii

```
FF Crystal Chronicles: The Crystal Bearers      
FF Crystal Chronicles: My Life as a King    
FF Crystal Chronicles: My Life as a Darklord
Final Fantasy IV: The After Years   
FF Crystal Chronicles: Echoes of Time
```

got this from: http://www.thefinalfantasy.com/games/

and: http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/PlayStation_Network

I just made it look nice.

Comment: If you want to cover the E-Shop, then the PS3 would be the console to get. I'll update the list later to include downloadable games.

Comment: Seems like PS4 also has Type 0 HD.

Comment: @Zero you are right.

Comment: Don't forget about X/X-2 HD Remaster

Comment: Adding to @Reafexus X/X-2 HD Remaster is also on PS3 and VII and VIII can be brought from PSN for the PS3. on iOS you can get Final Fantasy I - VI plus IV - After Years. also there is Final Fantasy Record Keeper which appears to be supported by Square but it's not found in their collection of games but someone else (however RK sprites do appear in articles on the Wikia so it might be an indication that it does have official backing from Square since the Wikia doesn't list any of those shitty third party CG/wallpaper collection apps)

Comment: I have Final Fantasy Record Keeper for Android. It is indeed a Final Fantasy derivative game, encompassing all FF games from I though XIII. I think it is a third party developer, but Square Enix is clearly involved in it's production as indicated by a splash screen when the game is started and all of the content contained in the game.

Comment: You can also play ps1 games on the ps3, so all the FF's for ps3 can be played on it as well.

Comment: Yea Playstation 1 is the wrong answer (for all the reasons mentioned in my answer haha)

Comment: When I originally posted my answer I completely forgot about digital downloads haha

Comment: I don't know what iOS has, but here is what is available on the Android Play Store: I, II, III, IV, IV: After Years, V, VI, Tactics: WotL, Dimensions, All the Bravest, and Final Fantasy Record Keeper. I have no idea if there's any other FF apps available that can be side-loaded onto Android. I also know that emulators exist, such as one for the PS1 which would theoretically grant access to VII, VIII, and IX.

Comment: You're missing a number of PC games. Final Fantasy VII and VIII were released on the PC not long after they first came out. The PC also eventually got ports of XIII and XIII-2. The remakes for III, IV and IV: The After Years are also on the PC.

Comment: I don't think you can play any of the PSN games on PS4.

Answer (score 4):

A PS3 can play at least every Final Fantasy from I to XIII-3 except for III and XII.

With backwards compatibility and PSClassics on PSN you can play:

Final Fantasy Origins - (Contains FFI and FFII)
Final Fantasy Chronicles - (Contains FFIV and Chrono Trigger)
Final Fantasy Anthology - (Contains FFV and FFVI)
Final Fantasy VII through IX

PS3 versions include X, X-2, XIII, XIII-2, and XIII Lighting Returns.

An original PS3 COULD have played XII. But the PS2 backwards compatibility which was discontinued early on.

Comment: [XI seems playable on a ps3](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/235/~/install-final-fantasy-xi-on-ps3)

Comment: Don't forget FFI & FFII through Final Fantasy Origins: http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_Origins

Comment: I did not know that existed. I might need to find it now haha.

Comment: 3 and 6 are the same game so technically you can play 3.

Comment: @Greatwon No, that's wrong. Final Fantasy 6 was called 3 outside of Japan, but Final Fantasy 3 is a different game that was remade and released on the DS, iOS, Android, and PC.

Comment: It was also released on the PSP, in both digital and UMD formats.

Comment: @twobugs you just blew my mind all this time I thought I had them all and beat them all...